# Processing large documents on server side

Tags: java, tomcat, server-side, large-files

- Some large documents (20 - 50 MB) are stored on the server side.
- A document can be loaded and queried (takes ~ 3 seconds) with a 3rd party program.
- Only one document can be loaded by the 3rd party program (at a given thread).
- Clients can request to view the query result of one of the loaded documents.

What is the best way to avoid loading a document upon each client http request?? 
Is it logical to keep all these loaded documents in memory?
If yes, would it require a thread pool, where each thread is holding a document?
If no, what are the other options?

(Working with Java - Tomcat - Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I would put another server in front of your tomcat to do some caching. If you implement this yourself, you're bound to run into problems. A setup might look like this:

`Client` → `Varnish Caching Server` → `Apache HTTP Server` → `Tomcat`

If you need HTTPS, you might consider putting another server before Varnish as it doesn't support SSL (as I recall). Then it might be like this:

`Client` → `Pound` → `Varnish Caching Server` → `Apache HTTP Server` → `Tomcat`

You can configure Varnish extensively with some kind of rule-language. It will serve you very nicely.

Pound is just a small reverse-proxy that you can use for terminating SSL and/or load balancing.

Links:

Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/

Varnish: https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Pound: http://www.apsis.ch/pound

Answer (score 0):

In case you are processing document by external program, tere is not much that you can do
except caching processing results  somewhere. Another option would be eagerly preprocess documents and store all possible query results for later retrieval.

Forking external process on every request is clearly worst option.

As your data is processed insiede web applicaton and is immutable you can just mmap
files into  byte buffers and work agains them. this way you will save  loading and 
allocation of data in your JVM.

And since your queries do not change data,there is no need to  push them to separate threads - they can access data from different threads serving http requests directly

Comment: I can't cache the results, as it is upon request, ex: (get me the information related to the position 30 -40)

and it is not an external program, it is a library that is called

finally:
I am thinking of a thread for each possible document.. these threads are always up and running... when an http request comes in, I query the correct thread based on which document the client is requesting...